# Scroll of "Recent inbox messages" doesn't work properly

Tags: bug, global-inbox

[image]

Scroll of "Recent inbox messages" is bigger than the content height. How you can see I'm able to scroll last seen message so high. But this scroll is not infinite. The scroll reaches the bottom exactly when the last message disappears

[image]

I propose two solutions to this problem:

- Fix scrolling
- Fill the empty space with more count of recent messages

Comment: [Report on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384205)

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you! Should I delete this post?

Comment: Not necessary. The same report can be on MSE and MSO. Just wanted to add a link, because otherwise it's harder to keep track. The company is already notified at any rate.